# update slider only after the slider stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-slider

I have a `knockout.js` slider using [`jquery-ui slider`](https://jqueryui.com/slider/).

```
<input id="ex2" data-slider-id="ex2Slider" type="text" data-bind="sliderValue: {value: borrowOrInvestAmount, min:0, max: 5000, step: 1, formatter:formatter2}, event: { change: $root.getInvestmentDetailsForBorrower }, valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']" style="display: none;">
```

So I tried using `value-update` but did not work. Now when I click on the slider points without dragging it, it works normally and calls `$root.getInvestment`, but I want that to be called right after the slider stops being dragged.

Now when I drag the slider, it stops on all the points till it reaches its target.

Comment: Please setup a minimal, complete and verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: slider using `juqery-ui` slider? like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/Dt7Ka/)?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia I just want to know a way to update my slider value when it stops moving, there is no less or more information needed.

Comment: @MoshFeu yea, I need to update the value after key down, but its not working in my case, it updates value in each step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error in my code I just wrote a bit too much in the valueUpdate, just writing this

```
valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'
```

Instead of this

```
valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace:

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidestop",..)
```

To

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidestop",...)
```

**And**

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slide", function (event, ui) {...
```

To

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "stop", function (event, ui) {...
```

This change will change the event that occur the changes from `slide` to `stop`.

**The working example:**

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
    $(element).slider(options);
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidestop", function (event, ui) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(ui.value);
    });
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).slider("destroy");
    });
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "stop", function (event, ui) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(ui.value);
    });
  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
    $(element).slider("value", value);
  }
};


var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.savings = ko.observable(10);
    self.spent = ko.observable(5);
    self.net = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.savings() - self.spent();
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>

<h2>Slider Demo</h2>

Savings: <input data-bind="value: savings, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<div style="margin: 10px" data-bind="slider: savings, sliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 100, range: 'min', step: 1}"></div>

Spent: <input data-bind="value: spent, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<div style="margin: 10px" data-bind="slider: spent, sliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 100, range: 'min', step: 1}"></div>

Net: <span data-bind="text: net"></span>
```